# How to use AVCaptureStillImageOutput to capture image to camera roll with geo location

Tags: ios, camera, location

I am developing for iOS9, and I have added captured image to camera roll with `PHAssetCreationRequest` but the geolocation information is missing.
Any help?

Comment: Is the geolocation supposed to be there by default? You will most likely need to accomplish this by yourself. You will need to ask the user for permission to get his location then find a way to inject the metadata into the image.

Comment: It seem to be the geolocation is not there by default. Thank you.